# How to change the Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.dll version

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have been scratching my head over this one for far too long, and I have found no information that helps online. I have tried to change the target/minimum frameworks, as well as try to update the packages which fail and say:

```
Unable to resolve dependencies. 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView 23.4.0' 
is not compatible with 'Xamarin.Forms 2.2.0.43 constraint: 
Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView (= 23.3.0)'.
```

And an error on deployment after a successful build:

```
The $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.dll (v6.0)
is greater than the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project (v4.4). 
You need to increase the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project. Squared    
C:\Users\USER\Repositories\SOLUTION\PROJECT\PROJECT.csproj
```

These errors arise for several packages simultaneously.

I would like to keep my frameworks as follows:
[image]

I think my next step is to try to change the Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.dll version, but I am not sure how to go about that.

Comment: Each version of `Xamarin.Forms` has a matching and required set of platform related assemblies and thus you can not change individual assemblies since they work as a complete version-dependent stack.

Comment: It seems you have updated one of the android support libraries in a Xamarin.Forms project. This is generally not a good idea as @SushiHangover suggests. Only update the Xamarin.Forms package and go with the versions it requires e.g. downgrade CardView to 23.3.0...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the field 'Compile using Android version:' you should use 'Android 6.0 (Marshmallow)'
If it doesn't exist in the list, install it from android sdk manager. (install the exact version 23.3.0)

For TargetFrameworkVersion you should edit .csproj file. Find this tag and change its value to 6.0

Comment: This isn't an proper answer, because he said he wanted to keep old framework. So do I, because current latest stable 7.1.1 doesn't have Google APIs in SDK manager, which I needed because Xamarin.Forms previewer requires some files and won't work when project is build for 7.1.1.

Comment: This question has been getting some more popularity, so i wanted to highlight the only action i needed to take was using the latest Android version to compile against.